# How to Debone Oxtail?

Tags: beef, knife-skills, hamburgers, oxtail, knife-safety

I was reading this burger recipe from Serious Eats: http://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2009/10/the-blue-label-burger-blend-recipe.html

It sounds great, but it calls for ground oxtail, which does not sound easy to produce. I have a set of cooking knives, but does anyone know if it will be feasible to attempt this without special equipment and/or a lot of knife skill? I was hoping to just get the meat from Whole Foods rather than a specialty butcher, so I can't count on them deboning it for me.

Comment: Sounds like a 1st of April recipe

Comment: Kenji speaks to this in the comment section.  Scroll down in the recipe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Let the butcher do it

This is roughly the bone structure of a mammal tail:

[image: tail bone structure]

As you can see, it has very many small bones, with of course all the connective tissue. Unless you have solid knife skill, a very sharp boning knife (with the needle-like blade), a protective chain mail glove, and ***lots*** of patience, I would say something like this is better left for a professional butcher. Especially if you have not done much boning, this could easily end up in an injury.

## For reference

#### Boning knives:

[image: boning knives]

#### Chainmain butcher glove:

[image: butcher glove]

Comment: Or if you're not super skilled but want to do it yourself carefully, just be careful and be satisfied with leaving a decent amount of meat on the bones. (You can still use them for stew later, so it's not really a waste!)